# How to use trigger to split data and transfer it to another table

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-workbench

**I want to create trigger that if added new row to table** *IDVU* ** it separates column** *UV* **that consists of string** ,example (Jo Black), **into two strings(words)** *Jo* **and** *Black* **that are inserted in table** *sep* **columns** *V*(for Jo) **and** *U*(for Black)

```
CREATE TRIGGER `edit` AFTER INSERT 
ON `idvu` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    IF new.VU = '% %' THEN
        SET @V = 'K' ,@U = 'P';
    else
        SET @V = 'NEW',@U = 'NEW';
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO sep (ID2,V, U) VALUES (new.ID,@V, @U);

END$$
```

In the end result should look like this:

[image: Table sep] from [image: Table UDIV]

The problem is I do not know have to split strings when using trigger?

*Excuse my script writing skills 4th day with MySQL! :) *

Answer (score 1):

**Turned out to be easy just add substring_index()**

```
create table IDVU (
`ID` int not null ,
`VU` varchar(45),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `ix_VU` (`VU`)
)ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Insert into idvu values (1,'Jo Black');

drop table sep;
create table sep select 
    idvu.id as ID2 ,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(VU, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) as V,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(VU, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) as U
        from IDVU;
Alter table sep add ID1 mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL primary key AUTO_INCREMENT first;
alter table sep add KEY `ix_ID2` (`ID2`)  ;
alter table sep add CONSTRAINT `C1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID2`) REFERENCES `IDVU`(`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

delimiter $$
drop trigger `edit` $$
CREATE TRIGGER `edit` AFTER INSERT 
ON `idvu` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    IF new.VU like '% %' THEN
        SET @V = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(new.Vu, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) ,
            @U = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(new.Vu, ' ', 2), ' ', -1);
    else
        SET @V = 'NEW',@U = 'NEW';
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO sep (ID2,V, U) VALUES (new.ID,@V, @U);

END$$

delimiter ;
```